# More than one Scala library found in the build path

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, buildpath

I am using `mac OS`, `spark 3.0.0` and `Scala.`

More than one Scala compiler `latest 2.12 bundle (dynamic)`.

However, when I ran my Scala code, I am getting the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2j/jpszz3613w13h186cbxwt7sc0000gn/T/liblz4-java-497947512819681458.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2j/jpszz3613w13h186cbxwt7sc0000gn/T/liblz4-java-497947512819681458.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Let me know if you need additional info about the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues/652#issuecomment-537036577

Comment: Thanks @howlger for your response. However, that post pertains to older version of spark and scala. My current mac OS is Sierra and latest spark 3.0.0 and scala complier 2.12 bundle. Also, the error they mentioned is a bit different. In my case, its                                                                                          Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2j/jpszz3613w13h186cbxwt7sc0000gn/T/liblz4-java-4177068872105682817.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find a fix for this?